# AWS CloudWatchEventsException. cloudwatchuser is not authorized to perform: events:PutEvents on resource

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

New to aws, I am trying to write a code in java to put events to cloud logs. But I am getting this error in java. I am not sure what I need to do in console.

software.amazon.awssdk.services.cloudwatchevents.model.CloudWatchEventsException: User: arn:aws:iam::***:user/cloudwatchuser is not authorized to perform: events:PutEvents on resource: arn:aws:events:us-east-1:****:event-bus/default because no identity-based policy allows the events:PutEvents action (Service: CloudWatchEvents, Status Code: 400

How to solve this issue???

I refereed to the official documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-cloudwatch-send-events.html

Comment: The error is clear. Your user does not have permissions.

Comment: The user `user/cloudwatchuser` don't have permission `events:PutEvents`